# WCF ResponseFormat JSON Returns Json in Fiddler, Xml in Chrome/Firefox!

Tags: c#, wcf, json

Hi I have a WCF Rest 4.0 project. For some reason I have a webservice which should return Json and it does if i hit the endpoint over fiddler but thru firefox or chrome if I type in the address I get xml. Whats going on???

Thanks for any help! Here's the code.

Web service in question:

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "",                  
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        public SomeObject [] GetObjects()
        {
              .....
```

Object code:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeObject
{      
        [DataMember]
        public string Date { get; private set; }

        ....
            public String Site { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Check your request headers.  "Accept" in particular.

Comment: What address you are typing in the address bar?

Comment: The uri the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the .NET 4.0 framework, this is the solution: http://karnicki.eu/2011/02/rest-wcf-net-4-0-service-with-json-jsonp-for-jquery/

WCF now has JSONP support out of the box with little configuration required.

Basically you just need to edit/add two config file entries, authenticationMode and StandardEndpoint, and voila, you can view json response from your WCF service in any browser.

EDIT: The original link is down - this might help: http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=696

Comment: Is there any other place where that post exists? Got the same problem and the link is dead to me.

Answer (score 2):

I posted this as a comment, but I'll add more detail here.

Your browser is most likely sending this header:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Note that it does not mention json but does mention xml.

Your WCF client is most likely using a different "Accept" header that gives a preference to json.  You can check this in Fiddler.

Comment: And this header let IIS to choose the response format automatically. See my answer `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"` to let the service decided the format on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cant display raw JSON, however you can use a tool like JSON viewer 
([http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home&ProjectName=jsonview](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home&ProjectName=jsonviewer)) or Fiddler is fit for that job too.

Comment: even when I hit "view source"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
[I used a WCF configuration with no svc](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx).

I had to change this boolean in web.config from true :

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
```

to false :

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
```